# How to change the swift file that will show on load programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I've got three different .swift files, GameScene.swift, GameOverScene.swift, and StartScene.swift. When I open my app, GameScene shows up. How can I change it so that StartScene.swift is the first file that is displayed? I have been working all in code so a way to do this without the storyboard would be nice. Thanks for the help!

EDIT:
I feel like I've got to change something in GameViewController.swift so heres the code for that.

```
extension SKNode {
class func unarchiveFromFile(file : String) -> SKNode? {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
        var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return scene
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("pauseTimers:"), name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("startTimers:"), name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)


    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
func pauseTimers(notification : NSNotification) {
    println("Observer method called")
    timer.invalidate()
    scoretimer.invalidate()
    supertimer.invalidate()
}

func startTimers(notification : NSNotification) {
    println("Observer method called")
    timerRecreate = true
    timerz = false
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

I tried changing everything that said gamescene to StartScene but that didn't work.

Heres the list of files:
[image]
And heres my app delegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game. 

}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}
```

EDIT:

I tried implementing the second method in the post below but I got three errors. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With storyboard go into your app delegate and look for this method

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject :AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
   self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
  }
```

If you aren't using Storyboard

```
window: UIWindow? 
var initialViewController :StartScene?
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject :AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

   initialViewController  = StartScene(nibName:"StartScene",bundle:nil)

    let frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    window = UIWindow(frame: frame)

    window!.rootViewController = initialViewController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
              ...
}
```

Comment: So if I wanted to make StartScene.swift the file that loads on startup do I need to make a viewcontroller for StartScene?

Comment: I've got Main.Storyboard but I don't have a view controller for StartScene.swift

Comment: From my understanding of your problem StartScene would be a subclass of a view controller. 

`var window: UIWindow?` 
`var initialViewController :StartScene?`

Comment: If you aren't using StoryBoard then use the second part of the answer, so it doesn't matter if you don't have a viewcontroller for StartScene in the storyboard. I assume StartScene is a ViewController. If its not then I would have to see a lot more of your code to help. Or I would recommend making it a subclass of UIViewController

Comment: I updated my initial post with all the files I have and my app delegate. I just did file create new swift file, I dont think StartScene is a view controller.

Comment: My bad I added the wrong screenshot without the StartScene.swift. Fixed now

Comment: When I added var initialViewController : StartScene? it says use of undeclared type StartScene